# How can I get the items from a ListView and convert these items to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

How can I **get the items from a ListView** and convert them to an **ArrayList**?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWHzT.png]

Screenshot: (in `mConversationArrayAdapter` must go the arraylist)

Comment: Can you show me how you created mConversationArrayAdaptor?

Comment: Check Arrays.asList method or ArrayList constructor where you can pass array as param

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a method in your adapter that gets the arrayList and then call that method where you need the data.

Something like this,

> ```
>  public ArrayList<String> getData(){
>      return this.arrayList; 
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a method in the adapter to get the values like this:

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mConversationArrayAdapter.get(position);
    }
```

Or get theem directly in your class.

But if you want to display the list, you must use "[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.html)" is better than ListView.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this.

```
ListView listView = new ListView();

    listView.getItems().add("Item1;");
    listView.getItems().add("Item;2");
    listView.getItems().add("Item3;");

     for (int i=0;i<listView.getItems().size();i++){
         String currentLine= (String) listView.getItems().get(i);
         String[] cells=currentLine.split(";");
         System.out.println(currentLine);
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cells));
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to add items, I want to get all of them and be able to access them as arraylist